# The Hunger Angst. Why the Arena tech yet the population is subjugated?

Tags: the-hunger-games

The Hunger Games stories demonstrate technology far beyond what we have today that are akin to Star Treks Molecular Machines. The arena can create force fields, creatures, water, terrain, food, tools, etc. instantly via computer templated information and plentifully available raw matter. For example, killer dogs in the first installment were injected into the environment as well as fire being directed toward Katnis demonstrating complete power over the atom.

In that society, people would not be fighting over scarce resources and the populations could be easily pacified by receiving all the goods they need rather than manual labor and starvation being the daily ritual of the less fortunate districts, inciting resentment and revolt of The Capitol.

This makes no sense to me as a political move. Is there some actual logic behind that?

Comment: You're making an unwarranted assumption that avoiding resentment and revolt is the goal, as opposed to political dominance.

Comment: My assumption is the need for control in which pacification is the means. That is the very reason for the "Hunger Games" correct?

Comment: The 12 districts are subjected to manual labor & starvation *because* they revolted against the Capitol

Comment: Can't check mark you if its a comment. Seems like a good answer but just fleshed out would be good.

Comment: It's a gap in the magnitude of production. Many futuristic-seeming technologies exist functionally today, but are not in wide production and/or use because the cost is prohibitive. Building an arena might seem like an enormous expense, but I'll bet it's peanuts compared to the cost of feeding and clothing a nation of hundreds of millions.

Comment: I don't recall *anything* in any of the books implying that things were being newly created on the fly.

Comment: We could feed the entire world today, if we wanted to.

Comment: @KharoBangdo that is circular reasoning. Let's start before the while-loop. Why the revolt in the beginning? If given resources-a-plenty, no revolt, everyone happy.

Comment: @lea Nano-tech is not expensive once deployed as energy is free taken from the sun and raw material of any sort (dirt, air, even shit) can be used to make anything as its just reconfiguring atoms and placing them together as molecules which the movies seem to demonstrate.

Comment: You fail to realize that some governments have been ruling this way for centuries.  You oppress people enough and they are too afraid to do anything about it.  It never works in the end, but neither does democracy.  Also, even in the movies, I do not recall any instances of Star Trek like technology, certainly not replication.

Comment: @phantom42: Agreed. It's pretty clear the dogs are being released from some kind of concealed holding area -- in much the same way the tributes themselves were brought into the arena. The Capitol clearly used advanced genetic engineering methods to create the dogs, but that's very different from magically making them appear out of thin air.

Comment: The arenas are specifically designed to "Shock and Awe" the outer districts with the Capitol's might. I imagine after restricting education in the districts for a few generations any kind of high-tech is starting to look like magic, per. Clarke's maxim.

Comment: @DaveJohnson thank you for pointing out my "failures". We have no precedent in history of this type of technology and its effect so we are very open to debate. I mean, seriously, the internet alone has done wonders for exposing inequality and inciting change.

Comment: Your question reminds me of [this](http://youtu.be/AxsjRmN9syc?t=3m) video (starts at 3:00). The whole video is amusing, but the very end makes it clear you're not the only person to wonder about this.

Comment: @Ellesedil  THANK YOU! Finally some validation. These people are acting like I'm making it up or something.

Comment: The whole reason for the games is to make the Capitol look a lot more powerful than they really are. It sure seems to be fooling a lot of people here in real life. Pretty cool meta, Ms. Collins!

Comment: @JeoL Ummmm. You are talking about a fictional universe. A movie in real life was depicting (rather clearly) of creating literal creatures from thin air and force fields etc. A movie (fiction) was fooling me in real life of what the fiction was claiming. Yah.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Because Panem is designed to keep all the best resources for The Capitol**

It's a matter of scale and politics.

First of all, the arenas are not all powerful manifestations of technology which, by the power of nano-tech can accomplish anything.  They have flaws and past combatants have leveraged those (Haymitch is included in this group).

The use of nano-tech or molecular manipulation is rarer than it seems.  In fact, in the books the hounds we see at the end aren't created out of thin air, but are [muttations](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/Muttation) - just like the mockingjays, and tracker jackers.  The "create dogs from nothing" effect was added for the movie, IIRC, and is a rare example of something being converted from one form to another.

That's not to say the arenas can't be technically impressive, flourishes of nano-tech or not.  Both the second book and movie show an arena with some extremely fine tuned control to it and, in honor of the 75th anniversary is even more complex than normal.

It was, however, also [notably smaller](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/Arena):

> This arena was very small, and circular in shape, which tipped Wiress off to the set-up of the clock mechanism.

Now compare having a couple rare instances of manipulating or controlling molecules, even as shown in the movies, within a small arena versus trying to provide all the goods for an area *[roughly the size of the United States and parts of Canada](http://thehungergames.wikia.com/wiki/Panem)*:

> Panem is a nation that was established during an unknown time period in a post-apocalyptic world. It is situated primarily in North America, and the Capitol is located in an area formerly known as the Rocky Mountains, as it states in the first book of the Hunger Games trilogy.

The difference in scale is massive.  And The Capitol prefers to keep all of the best technology and consume the best resources themselves, so you can bet that any practical use of any kind of technology we see in the arenas would be first applied to The Capitol.

Keeping the technology and the resources regulated is part of Panem's strategy to quell further resistance.  While some districts (notably 2 and 3, industry and electronics) are more modern than others (Katniss is frequently assumed to basically be a country bumpkin due to her origins) - by keeping the all of the best technology and resources to themselves, The Capitol assume they can crush any uprising through technological superiority.

Comment: This should be higher voted because he actually cites examples from the stories. Although, the movies embellish the tech for more than it is according to people's comments.

Comment: I think this is also the case where lore gets trampled by movie producers and then lore gets entangled with lore/not lore like Schrödinger's Cat.

Answer (score 5):

What do we see in the arenas, really? A plot of land (cheap), surrounded by a force-field (relatively cheap - probably a single field-generator, easily overloaded, running for a few days), some holographic tricks (again, cheap), a bunch of genetically-engineered monsters and poison plants (relatively cheap as well as good practice for their bio-weapons division), fire (easy) and special effects. All set up in advance in a small area, kept running for a week or less. The only thing that seemed to be done "on the fly" was giving the dog-things the features of the fallen tributes, and that could have been set up in advance as well (if it wasn't just Kat's imagination).

You have to look at the games as a whole, not just the taking of tributes. It's a relatively inexpensive display of power meant to keep the districts in line. But while it's all very impressive-looking most of it's just smoke-and-mirrors.

There's no specific cite, but the books make it clear that the Capitol is good at biotech, medicine, chemistry and other low-energy, small-scale production items. What they *don't* have is a lot of high-energy-use items (such as aircraft and tanks) that require large-scale production lines. They do have *some,* but nothing like any industrialized nation has today. Nanotech (the reality of nanotech, not the magical do-anything kind seen so often in SF) would be a natural for them, but I don't recall seeing any explicit mention of it in the books or the movies (nanotech can make a lot of neat things possible, but it can't break the laws of physics, like make something out of nothing without taking time and energy).

In short, the Capitol just doesn't have the production capacity to do very much, other than keep everyone else down. And they even fail at that pretty fast once *all* of the districts start fighting back.

Comment: Its crystal clear in the movies that its nano-tech. I did not read the books in which my mind would make up a picture of whatever I interpreted as you have. However, books have a much more personal meaning in that regard so not knocking reading in any sense, just citing the movie interpretation as my source.

Comment: It might be more accurate to say the Capitol is good at biotech, medicine and chemestry, and other low-energy, small-scale production items. They don't have a lot of high-energy-use items that require large-scale production lines. Some, but nothing like any industrialized nation has today. Nanotech (the reality of nanotech, not the magical do-anything kind seen so often in SF) would be a natural for them. I don't recall seeing any explicitly, though, in the books or the movies. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially the reason that everyone is subjugated is because in the last war that the capitol won everyone else either was on the loosing side or did not help. Hence why they live in squalor and every year they have the hunger games to make them watch how helpless they are while they kill 2 kids from your district.